# Is full width navigation a bad method on CSS?

Tags: html, css, web

Top navigation is the common way but full width top navigation is rare. When you hover the submenus open in a standard width starting from its parent or ending on its parent position.

I have made many searches on the web but there was not a good example on full width navigation that shows submenus in blocks and lists, as code example. Is that a bad idea or why there is no good examples on that?

Examples:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/default.aspx

http://www.oracle.com/index.html

http://www.hizlisaat.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for this tutorial:
http://designmodo.com/create-css3-mega-menu/

Comment: This was a very good one, thank you for this. There are many few good examples about this topic useful.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a bad idea though its not used much it is used here though

[BBC Homepage](http://www.bbc.co.uk)

Comment: I think so but there is no working codes on the net so I wonder.